# Qué sigue después de una cadena String

Tags: c#, string

Me gustaría saber que sigue después de una cadena string
tengo esto:

```
string cadena = "abc";
if(cadena[cadena.length +1] == null)
{
  ....
}
```

por lógica sabemos que me mostrará un error porque excedió el indice. 
pero yo necesito saber que existe después de "C", null, vacío, etc.
¿Es esto posible?

Comment: Y por qué necesitas saber eso? Si estás tratando de resolver un problema, es mejor que especifiques cual.Tal como está, la pregunta no tiene mucho sentido.

Comment: muy buena pregunta, la respuesta es un tanto compleja, ya que hay que mirar como se guardan las variables en memoria y como se manejan los punteros, en este caso el valor que le sigue a esa referencia del string en memoria no existe, no existe un valor logico, pero a algún lado ira a buscar no es asi, y el error se da cuando se busca fuera de la referencia de la variable, normalmente el error es un desbordamiento de la pila o la famosa stack overflow exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptualmente no hay nada después, en el sentido de que la cadena ha terminado.

En lenguajes donde no existe este control de la memoria (por ejemplo en C) y podamos acceder al siguiente registro, lo que hay después varía según la implementación: Para empezar, en C no existe el tipo String, es un array de caracteres. Es habitual que el último carácter sea el carácter número 0 (ojo, no el `"0"`, sino el equivalente a hacer `char nul= 0;`) para que cuando se recorra el array sepamos cuándo parar.

En lenguajes donde exista la clase String, es posible que lo que venga después sea algún atributo del objeto (su longitud, por ejemplo), pero puedes, en general, considerarlo así:

Si llegamos al final del array y no nos detenemos, lo siguiente que leamos será *basura* (asumiendo que no nos hemos salido del espacio de memoria asignado a nuestro proceso y el sistema operativo no nos cierra la aplicación). Es decir, estaremos leyendo zonas de memoria que pueden pertenecer a otra variable, o no pertenecer a nada porque no se han asignado todavía.

Si conoces bien como funciona el compilador, en algunos casos podrás predecir lo que te vas a encontrar.

En C#, donde intentar llegar más allá dará un error, no puedes leer zonas de memoria de ese modo: si la siguiente dirección pertenece a alguna variable/objeto, deberás usar su identificador para acceder a su valor.

En otras palabras: tu programa asigna espacios de memoria para cada objeto/estructura que necesitas, y lo normal (no conozco otro caso) es hacerlo de manera consecutiva: en la posición N empieza el objeto String, que guardará los caracteres de manera consecutiva, pero además guardará la longitud, punteros a sus métodos, a los de la clase padre (Object), los atributos que pueda tener Object y String internamente y no vemos... etc.

En la posición (N + tamaño del objeto String + 1) posiblemente empezará otro objeto

Comment: Eso he estado leyendo, es que estoy haciendo un compilador que me detecte palabras reservadas, signos, operadores etc. Pero supongo que tengo mal mi lógica. Porque puedo leer un if(a > 4) pero no un if(a >4 cusndo el operador está antes de una cadena o número

Comment: Eso es un tema de identificar los tokens correctamente, definiendo la gramática. Para eso ya existen herramientas como Lex, JLex, C#Lex ...

Comment: Como sospechaba, esto tiene pinta de ser un claro ejemplo de [el problema XY](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3360/15301). @IsmarMiranda te aconsejo que leas el enlace.

Comment: gracias por su ayuda 0/ me sirvió mucho